# Redirect request to specific target groups using ALB listener

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

I have 1 ALB (`www.example.com`) with a rule forwarding all the HTTPS request to `target_group_A`.
So if send the request `GET www.example.com/something`, `target_group_A` will receive a request `GET /something`.

Now, I defined a second target group `target_group B`. My goal is to redirect all requests to `www.example.com/svc_B` to `target_group B`.
For example if I send the request `GET www.example.com/svc_b/something`, I want that `target_group_B` receive a request `GET /something` and not `GET /svc_b/something`

I have a rule which forward all request to `www.example.com` to `target_group_A` and an rule above this one which forward all requests to `www.example.com` to `target_group_B` if the path contains `/svc_b`. It works but `target_group_B` receive the the full path with `/svc_b/` but I want all path after `svc_b` like my example above.

How can I do this type of forwarding?